# gitconfig shell-command aliasing runs from top-level rather than current directory

Tags: git, git-config

I've written a bash script called `git_diff_parent` which, when passed a commit handle, performs `git diff commit~1 commit`; in other words, it diffs with its ancestor without having to specify `commit~1` on the command line. I do this by parsing the git command line, finding which argument is the commit string (using `git cat-file -t`), replacing it with `commit~1 commit` then passing the new argument list to `git diff`. I've aliased this script in `/etc/gitconfig` so I can execute this command as `git diff-parent`:

```
[alias]
   diff-parent = !git_diff_parent
```

This ***almost*** works except when I try to diff an individual file from a place other than the top-level repository directory, e.g.:

```
% pwd
/home/myhome/github/my-branch/rtl
% git diff-parent branch -- mycode.sv
<no output>
% git diff-parent branch -- rtl/mycode.sv
<diff output appears>
```

To debug this, I added `pwd` to my script to see the script's working directory. Lo and behold, it always launches from the top-level directory (`/home/myhome/github/my-branch`) rather than the subdirectory I'm in. I've even tried `git -C . diff-parent ...` to no avail.

So is there any way to make my alias launch from the current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias

> Note that shell commands will be executed from **the top-level directory of a repository**, which may not necessarily be the current directory. **`GIT_PREFIX`** is set … from the original current directory.

(Emphasize and cut are mine — *phd*)

So you can do `cd $GIT_PREFIX` in `git_diff_parent` shell script.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you! One minor tweak: **`GIT_PREFIX`** is unset if you run from the top-level directory, so you need to catch that condition with something like `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` so it "changes" to the current directory in that case.